# AWS EC2 Instance Metadata service fails to respond

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, metadata

Environment, system details, and tools:

- AWS EC2
- EC2 Instance Metadata service (i.e. http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/)
- Cloudwatch
- wget
- bash
- Ubuntu 14.04

Has anyone ever seen this? We have a cron job that pushes Cloudwatch metrics from inside an instance by basically doing these steps:

1. Get instanceId by running "wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id"
2. Collecting some metric or other and building an AWS CLI query using `aws cloudwatch put-metric-data ...`
3. Repeat

The weird thing we are seeing is, very infrequently, one of these runs will die after the `wget` query, with no output. As if the Metadata service just failed to respond.

Example end-of-script (we set bash -e and -x to die and to gather debug output):

```
++ wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
+ INSTANCE_ID=
```

The script ends there and exits because presumably `wget` exited with a non-zero exit status.

This is not reproducible, but it happens on the order of once every 2 weeks.

Comment: It seems like the first thing you'd want to do is to not suppress the actual error you're hitting, which you're doing by specifying `-q`.  The output from `-O -` goes to `STDOUT` but all the other nonsense wget normally spews on a successful request goes to `STDERR`, so there isn't an actual need to suppress it when you're capturing its output.

Comment: ...although you could reduce the spew somewhat by trimming some known nonsense from the `STDERR` stream with something like `INSTANCE_ID=$(wget -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2> >(perl -pe 'undef $_ if /^Length/ || /^Saving\ to/ || /written\ to\ stdout/ || /100%/ || /^$/' >&2))` ... or just use `INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)`, which might also provide a useful error -- not sure, since I've never encountered this problem.

Comment: Thanks. My colleague and I just discussed removing `-q`, so we'll probably do that. Beyond that though, I'm going to wrap this call in a retry loop and call it a day. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could be throttled. Specially if the issue is inconsistent.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-throttling

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers  Can you make your answer stand on it own?